# htaccess redirect and hide directory name

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

have had a good look through the archives here without success so hopefully someone can help me here.

Basically I need to redirect to a directory in my root called 'trunk'.
I have put an htaccess file in my root which includes this link:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mysite/trunk/$1 [L]
```

This redirects perfectly as I wish to the correct page ie mysite.com/trunk/site/login

What I really need to do now is remove the 'trunk' from the url if possible but still have the site pointing to this page.

How can I best do this please?

Many thanks

Comment: sorry the top part of my question above has disappeared but the content is there. Thanks all, Lew

Comment: Do your pages refer to `trunk` in the URL's? If your .htaccess redirect rule is setup correctly, then all you should need to do is modify the URL's you have within the content so they don't mention `trunk`...

Comment: Provide some examples to explain your question better.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mywebsite/trunk/
RewriteRule ^mywebsite/(.*)$ /mywebsite/trunk/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /mywebsite/trunk/([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /mywebsite/%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: To clarify: basically when I go to my url ie localhost:8888/mywebsite I need this to point to the 'trunk' folder inside of that, otherwise I have to manually input localhost:8888/mywebsite/trunk .

The htaccess line I provided ie RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mywebsite/trunk/$1 [L] Redirects to the directory perfectly but also includes 'trunk' in the url.
To clarify, I want my home page to be mywebsite/site/login but the true url will be mywebsite/trunk/site/login.

The 'trunk' element of the url is what I need to get rid of ideally. Unfortunately the comment above didnt work but thanks very much anyway

Comment: @lcainswebdeveloper just add `/mywebsite/` in front of all the URI's. Also, these rules need to go into the htaccess file in your document root.

Comment: Thanks Jon, unfortunately this isn't working for me. The redirect even stops working with this for some reason. I really appreciate you trying to help though so thanks anyway.

Comment: @lcainswebdeveloper sorry, left out the `mywebsite` in one place